# Convert CSS content to HTML entity

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

Let's say I have element css like:

```
.dashicons-editor-help:before {
    font-family: dashicons !important;
    content: "\f223";
}
```

How would I convert `"\f223"` to HTML entity like `&#223;`. In some cases like `<select>`'s `<option>` you're not able to use pseudo elements and then it would be useful.

Also is there any way of automating the process of translating such CSS to HTML entities (let's say some CSS have 1000 font's like that).

I've found https://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html this tool, but it converts HTML entity to CSS content, I need reverse.

Comment: Misspelled last comment .. The link you have does the job, add `\f223` as decimal and you get `&#223;`, which gives `ß` in this case ... or did I misread something?

Comment: `&#` works like `&#<DECIMAL>;` not hex. Hex f223 is much more in decimal than 223 ( f223 in hex is around 63000 in decimal )

Comment: The character reference for `\f223` is simply `&#xf223;`, or am I seriously misunderstanding something?

Comment: Also, they're not called entities. Entities are names for things like `nbsp` and so on. Numerical codes are characters. So `&nbsp;` is an entity reference and `&#xf223;` is a character reference.